# A two-dimensional array with different datatypes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a situation of creating approximately 8 tables, each with a different number of columns. Each column represents a SUBJECT / COURSE chosen by each student.

On table 1, I want to show the courses applicable for semester 1 and on table 2 show courses for semester 2 and so on.

Somewhat like this `SemesterCourses<Integer,<ACourse>>` with `ACourse` being the course object. I have one row for each course for a semester. I want to read all the courses for a given semester and load it in the ARRAY/MAP/OBSERVABLELIST ???? and then pass it on to the next function which would create columns for each COURSE in this collection.

I need these arrays for each semester in memory. Otherwise, I can read from database and create the column and forget the course info.

Is there any way that I can create this type of LIST? I tried `Array<ACourse>[8][]` because the number of semesters is 8 and is constant. But I get syntax errors.

Comment: Map<Integer, List<Course>>

Comment: Or, since the keys to that map are just the index of the semester (so they'll be a contiguous range of integers), just `List<List<Course>>`.

Comment: Some students take more than 8 semesters to graduate from college.

Comment: This is in continuation to the problem specified above.

Comment: This is what I want.

Comment: Is there a way I can attach an EXCEL sheet ? I want to show what I want as final output ?